# How to solve this nested-loop without compiler?

Tags: python

I am beginner programmer, Today I have a question in my school exam. I want to know How to effectively solve these kinds problem without compiler?

```
x=0
for i in range(0,5):
    for j in range(0,i):
        k = i+j-1
        if k%2==0:
            x=x+k
        elif k%5==0:
            x=x+k-2
        print x,
    print x
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "without compiler"? You could use paper and a pencil.

Comment: Yes I am how to do this using dry run?

Comment: Write a table with all variables used in the code. In every row write the value of every variable after executing the next line of code.